# Pipe files downloaded with wget into a function

Tags: files, scripting, pipe, wget

I'm downloading a bunch of images with wget and I want to rm the files if they are empty with a function to which I can pass the file. My question is how do I pipe the images to a function like this:

```
rmEmpty ()
{
    if ! [ -s "$1" ]
    then
        rm "$1";
    fi
}
```

The way I download the images is

```
wget -q -O- http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/artwork/340782-official-digital-rendering-thread?page=$i | 
sed -n '{/forum-post-body-content/,/p-comment-notes/p}' |
grep -Po 'src="\K[^"]+' | xargs wget -q -T 6 -t 1
```

So I would like something like `xargs wget | rmEmpty()` at the end, if that's possible.

Comment: How do you download the (multiple) files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, prefer using `wget -i -` over `xargs wget`, because the `xargs` way might run (sequentially) several `wget` commands (if you have a lot of URL to retrieve) while the `wget -i -` will run only one (and therefore, if the remote server supports it, use the same TCP connexion).

Writing your own `rmEmpty` function is useless, since `find . -empty -type f -delete` will do the job (better).

To sum up:

```
BASE_URL="http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/artwork/340782-official-digital-rendering-thread?page=$i"
wget -q -O- "$BASE_URL" | \
    sed -n '{/forum-post-body-content/,/p-comment-notes/p}' | \
    grep -Po 'src="\K[^"]+' | wget -i - -q -T 6 -t 1

find . -maxdepth 1 -empty -type f -delete
```

I've added the `-maxdepth 1` to avoid problems if you run this script in a directory with a lot of subdirectories (your `$HOME` for example). You should run this script from a dedicated directory (empty before you run the script).

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is the evil

Comment: My answer focuses on the "remove empty files" part (which *is* the question asked), the rest has been taken from the OP. BTW I don't care if it's evil or not, it's efficient *in certain cases* and I prefer to avoid "principled stances" that prevent from thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Using a proper HTML parser in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
$m->get("http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/artwork/340782-official-digital-rendering-thread?page=1");
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $m->content );
my @imgs = $tree->findvalues( '//div[@class="j-comment-body-container p-comment-body forum-post-body-content"]//img/@src' );
`wget -i - -q -T 6 -t 1 @imgs; find . -maxdepth 1 -empty -type f -delete`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
rmEmpty ()
{
    if ! [ -s "$1" ]
    then
        rm "$1"
    fi
}
```

or even shorter :

```
rmEmpty() { [ -s "$1" ] || rm -f "$1"; }
```

Then :

```
for $file in *; do
    rmEmpty "$file"
done
```

Comment: I already know how to do that but I don't know if it is possible to pipe the file from wget.